# Struts2_bundle validation.xml not working

Tags: xml, struts2

Hey guys i am new to Struts 2 & i am not able to find out my bug.I have already seen similar question but i didn't get success till now.

I am doing validation in Struts2 using bundle_validators, but the problem is Validation is not done at RUNTIME when i execute the program.

> my bean & validation.xml is in src/actions package-

My ActionLogin.java

```
package actions;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class ActionLogin extends ActionSupport {

    private String name,email,password;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String execute(){

        return "success";
    }




}
```

Register-validation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC "-//OpenSymphony Group//XWork Validator 1.0.2//EN" "http://www.opensymphony.com/xwork/xwork-validator-1.0.2.dtd">




<validators>
<field name="name">
    <field-validator type="requiredstring">
    <param name="trim">true</param>
       <message>User Name is required.</message>
    </field-validator>
</field>

<field name="email">
    <field-validator type="requiredstring">
    <param name="trim">true</param>
       <message>Email is required.</message>
    </field-validator>
</field>

</validators>
```

My struts.xml is in WEB-INF/classes directory

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD  
Struts Configuration 2.1//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.1.dtd">  



<struts>



<include file="struts-default.xml"/>

<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
<package name="actions" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">

<action name="register" class="actions.ActionLogin" method="execute">



<result name="success">/welcome.jsp</result>
<result name="input">index.jsp</result>

</action>

</package>


</struts>
```

My index.jsp file is

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

    <%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
    <%@taglib uri="/struts-dojo-tags" prefix="d" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<STYLE type="text/css">  
.errorMessage{color:red;}  
</STYLE>  
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>



</head>
<body>

<s:form action="register">
<s:textfield name="name" label="name"></s:textfield>
<s:password name="password" label="Password"></s:password>
<s:textfield name="email" label="Email"></s:textfield>
<s:submit value="login"></s:submit>

</s:form>

</body>
</html>
```

Please help me find out my bug.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You must change the name of your validation xml file to this: ActionLogin-validation.xml
Struts2 convention for validation is like this ActionClass-validation.xml for ActionClass.java.
Both files (.java & .xml) must be in the same package
 In your case the action class is: ActionLogin.java so the validation file must be ActionLogin-validation.xml

Comment: @user3728064- Thanks for help..but still validation not working.My both files i.e ActionLogin.java & ActionLogin-validation.xml are in same pack..i.e src/actions...IS IT CORRECT??

Comment: I just noticed that you put the struts conf file in WEB-INF. Struts.xml file must be in the src directory of the App. <br>Also delete the namespace attribut in package declaration in struts conf file. Check this link, you'll find an image of the right app hierarchy<br>[link](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img537/3047/GPT3Ki.png)